# How to make deleted entities unavailable immediately during concurrency in Google App Engine (java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a servlet that gets list of entities based on request parameters and cache them in local List variable before deleting them immediately. Operations are performed with the list of objects after deletion.

Sometimes if servlet gets concurrent requests at once, both requests are able to get same entities and operations are performed twice which shouldn't occur.

I verified deletion time, it is around 100 milliseconds approximately. I need to make other concurrent request shouldn't able to read deleted entities.

How to handle this issue efficiently during concurrency across Google App Engine instances?

Comment: Use [Transactions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions)?

Comment: AS everyone else has said, use transactions. In addition fetching by Key rather than queries combined with transactions will also you encountering issues with eventual consistancy.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: So, are you using multiple instances of your servlet?

Comment: @Slava Imeshev it is a simple servlet but GAE server maintains multiple instances.

Comment: Of course, the question is, is it running in a single GAE instance / server or multiple instances?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use transactions to isolate the concurrency problems and create
a idempotent request. In Java, something like this:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

PreparedQuery pq = createYourQuery(datastore); // remember to setKeysOnly()

for (Entity entity : pq.asIterable()) {

    try {
        Transaction tx = datastore.beginTransaction();
        try {
            datastore.get(entity.getKey());
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            continue;
        }
        datastore.delete(entity.getKey());
        tx.commit();
    } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
        continue;
    }

    // execute your extra stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks @feroult for your detailed explanation along with code, I'll try with Transactions once but it might become bottleneck (due to Read operations too should be in transaction) as it handles very frequent requests. I have also another idea of implementing synchronization with Appengine Memcache storing some flag that says deleted to another request.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to tell without looking at the code, but generally the behavior you observe is a result of unsynchronized read/write access to the shared data structure, a list in your case. If that's the case, what you may do is to synchronize the blocks that read/write your list. Here is Java pseudo-code:

```
/**
 * Read from the cache.
 */
Data getCache(String key) {
  synchronized (this) {
     // ... Do read
  }
}

/**
 * Delete the cache.
 */
void clearCache() {
  synchronized (this) {
     // ... Do cleanup
  }
}
```

Comment: Since Appengine has a distributed architecture, the synchronization will not work across different JVMs,